# How to convert OSM data to a projected Coordinate system

Tags: shapefile, openstreetmap, coordinate-system

What is the easiest way to get OSM data into a shapefile projected data format for QGIS?
Sounds simple but I've run into problems with this before.

Comment: The key here is projected

Answer (score 2):

Try **[WeoGeo](http://market.weogeo.com/datasets/osm-openstreetmap-planet.html)** - it is a while since I gave their free OpenStreetMap download service a successful test but I believe it will meet your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

There are several script called `osm2shp` that do what you want, or you can use QGIS.

For an overview, see 
[this wiki page](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Shapefiles#Making_shapefiles_from_OpenStreetMap_data)

Once you have the data in a shapefile, you can reproject it into any CRS you want.